# Script not working as expected

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7, field-mapping

I'm newbie to python and I wrote this script. It is supposed to check the text in the fields `fld_o` and `fld_d` and write a value (just numbers in a sequence) to a newly created field `fld_name`. While looping if it comes across a text in either of the two fields which was already there is any of the previous rows in either of the fields then it should write the same value from that previous row to this row in the new field. The script ran without problems. But somehow the results are not as expected. You can see the two rows highlighted both have `Werl` in common so how can they have a different number in the new field? When the loop reaches the first highlighted row it should add `Werl` to the dictionary and assign it the same value as `Hamm` i.e. 54 and write it to the new field and then later when it reaches the second highlighted row it should take the already assigned value of 54 from `Werl` and assign this to `Wickede` and write it in the new field as well. At least that's what I expected.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc_in = 'E:/SUT/Thesis/Geodata/NRW_Gemeinde_SpatialJoin_SelectCopy.shp'

fld_o = 'GEN'
fld_d = 'GEN_1'
fld_name1 = 'Sub_Region'

arcpy.AddField_management(fc_in, fld_name1, 'SHORT') 

dct = {}
sub_region = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_in, (fld_o, fld_d, fld_name1)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        origin = row[0]
        dest = row[1]
        if origin in dct and dest in dct:
            row[2] = dct[origin]
        elif origin in dct: 
            row[2] = dct[origin]
            dct[dest] = dct[origin]
        elif dest in dct:
            row[2] = dct[dest]
            dct[origin] = dct[dest]
        else:
            sub_region = sub_region + 1
            row[2] = sub_region
            dct[origin] = sub_region
            dct[dest] = sub_region

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this will perform what you are looking for.  It iterates the first two fields of each row and compares each value to the dct.

```
dct = {}
subregion = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_in, (fld_o, fld_d, fld_name1)) as cursor:
    for row in rows:
        for i in row[:2]:
            if not i in dct.keys():
                dct[i] = subregion 
                subregion += 1
            row[2] = dct[i]
   cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You don't say what preference should be given if both of the strings have occurred before in either of the two fields...  If that matters you'd need a bit more.

EDIT:  As to why your script isn't working correctly: it's tricky to figure it out from here because in your screenshot you have sorted the rows by the "GEN_1" field.  The cursor will iterate the rows based on the FID field, so I'd recommend sorting the table by that field before further debugging efforts...

If you want the script to iterate the rows based on the GEN_1 field, you'll have to migrate this shapefile to a geodatabase, then you can use a sql clause to sort the cursor before you iterate it.  [Here's more info](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000).

EDIT 2:  I'm sure the script is working just fine, but the way you have set up the if/elif/else commands is a little confusing to me, as is the premise.  In you description of what you want, you say that it should "if it comes across a text in either of the two fields which was already there is any of the previous rows in either of the fields then it then it should write the same value from that previous row to this row in the new field."

The problem is that with this script you are never checking rows, only single items in each row.  When you update the dct for a single item you will lose the possibility of referencing a "row".  Basically, I'm not convinced that the goal you are trying to accomplish makes sense.  If you could fill in the x's below with the desired numbers, it would help me figure out exactly what you're actually trying to accomplish.

```
gen | gen_1 | sub_region
a | b | XXXX
e | b | XXXX
b | c | XXXX
c | d | XXXX
c | e | XXXX
a | f | XXXX
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like another nice way to do it. But it would be helpful if you could point out the problem in my script. And by the way if both strings have occurred before then the same value from the row before is to be written in the current row in the new field. I have already tried to do that in my script.

Comment: added a little more info to the answer...

Comment: Actually I wrote the script assuming that it will be sorted on the GEN field. I just migrated the shapefile to database and sorted by GEN field using ORDER BY sql clause. But it still doesn't give the correct result. I don't know why something that the script should clearly do is not being done, although the script runs without errors.